# Jq grid pager value displayed 1 of 0

Tags: html, jsp, jqgrid, pager

```
<td dir="ltr">Page <input class="ui-pg-input" type="text" size="2" maxlength="7" value="0" role="textbox"> of <span id="sp_1_pager">0</span></td>
```

The pager is displayed as 1 of 0. even though the html code gives correct value 0, it is rendered as 1. It happens when there are no records. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Put a check for data availability. If there is no data hide the pager and display a msg of no data available.

You can change the page function that is returning pager value like

```
page: function (obj) { return obj.length > 0 ? "1" : "0"; }
```

Comment: But this shouldn't happen r8. ideally we are setting the pager default in the jqgrid for this scenario and to display proper values when there is no record